# Cypher - Query Optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

My question is why `WHERE` operator is not working as fast as expected?
Consider I have 7 nodes with label `Consumer`. Here is some sample data...

```
MERGE (c:Consumer {mobileNumber: "000000000000"})
MERGE (:Consumer {mobileNumber: "111111111111"})
MERGE (:Consumer {mobileNumber: "222222222222"})
MERGE (:Consumer {mobileNumber: "333333333333"})
MERGE (:Consumer {mobileNumber: "444444444444"})
MERGE (:Consumer {mobileNumber: "555555555555"})
MERGE (:Consumer {mobileNumber: "666666666666"})
WITH c
MATCH (c1:Consumer) WHERE c1.mobileNumber <> "000000000000"
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_CONTACT]->(c1)
```

And there is a `HAS_CONTACT` relationship in between `:Consumer(mobileNumber:{"000000000000"})` and all other 6 nodes. Also there is a `unique index` constraint on `mobileNumber` field. Now when I try to execute below query:

```
    PROFILE MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber : "000000000000"}),
    (m:Consumer{mobileNumber : "111111111111"}) 
    WITH n,m 
    MATCH path = SHORTESTPATH((n)-[contacts:HAS_CONTACT]-(m)) 
    RETURN contacts;
```

So its working fine as expected(Search nodes on the basis of unique index). Below is its result:
[image: Without Where clause]

Now let change above query using `WHERE` clause:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber : "000000000000"}),
(m:Consumer) WHERE m.mobileNumber 
IN (["111111111111"]) 
WITH n,m 
MATCH path = SHORTESTPATH((n)-[contacts:HAS_CONTACT]-(m)) 
RETURN contacts;
```

Query Result:
[image: With WHERE clause]

Now although above query is working fine, and giving same result as that of old one. But for endNode where I have used `WHERE` clause, it doesn't uses any indexes. It first searches for all existing nodes, and then filter result using `WHERE` clause, which can be too expensive if there are hundreds of thousands of nodes with same label.

So my Questions are:

1. Why it doesn't uses indexes when I use `WHERE` clause?
2. What is the best way to refer multiple nodes with less number of db hits?
3. Can I use `IN` operator while expecting index search?

Comment: It is quite possible that query planner is making it's plan based on the nature of the the nature of the data in your database. I did use your data and second query in my local 3.2.2 CE. I created an constraint on `:Consumer(mobileNumber)`. And running it I received the results you expected.

Answer (score 3):

As @DaveBennett said, this problem does not seem to exist in version 3.2.2.

If you are using a prior version, try providing [hints](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/using/#query-using-index-hint) to the planner that it should use indexing:

```
PROFILE MATCH
  (n:Consumer{mobileNumber : "000000000000"}),
  (m:Consumer)
USING INDEX n:Consumer(mobileNumber)
USING INDEX m:Consumer(mobileNumber)
WHERE m.mobileNumber  IN (["111111111111"])
MATCH path = SHORTESTPATH((n)-[contacts:HAS_CONTACT]-(m))
RETURN contacts;
```

This might also work, since some planners seem to automatically attempt to use indexing on (only) the first `MATCH` term:

```
PROFILE MATCH
  (n:Consumer{mobileNumber : "000000000000"}),
  (m:Consumer)
USING INDEX m:Consumer(mobileNumber)
WHERE m.mobileNumber  IN (["111111111111"])
MATCH path = SHORTESTPATH((n)-[contacts:HAS_CONTACT]-(m))
RETURN contacts;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Actually at that time I was using Cypher version: CYPHER 3.1.* which was not using Indexes with "WHERE" clause. But now when I have updated my Neo4j to version 3.2.2, its working as expected.

Comment: Also I have tried above queries as you suggested, but still it doesn't work, giving same result, but after updating to newest version, now its working fine, Thanks. +1

Answer (score 2):

What version are you running? I am using 3.2.2 community edition and your second query generated the result you were seeking in my local instance with your small test data set.

That said, does the query planner change its approach with something like this in your instance?

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n:Consumer {mobileNumber : "000000000000"})
WITH n,(["111111111111", "222222222222", "333333333333", "444444444444", "555555555555", "666666666666"]) as number_list
UNWIND number_list as number
MATCH (m:Consumer {mobileNumber : number})
MATCH path = SHORTESTPATH((n)-[contacts:HAS_CONTACT]-(m)) 
RETURN contacts;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Actually at that time I was using Cypher version: CYPHER 3.1.* which was not using Indexes with "WHERE" clause. But now when I have updated my Neo4j to version 3.2.2, its working as expected. +1

Answer (score 0):

The indexes are actually used with the `WHERE` clause in this example:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber : "000000000000"}),
(m:Consumer) WHERE m.mobileNumber = "111111111111"
WITH n,m 
MATCH path = shortestPath((n)-[contacts:HAS_CONTACT]-(m)) 
RETURN contacts
```

which uses indexes as your first query. If you want to refer to multiple nodes you can use logical predicates like:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber : "000000000000"}),
(m:Consumer) WHERE m.mobileNumber = "111111111111" OR m.mobileNumber = "222222222222"
WITH n,m 
MATCH path = shortestPath((n)-[contacts:HAS_CONTACT]-(m)) 
RETURN contacts
```

or `AND` instead of `OR`.

I think that the current version of Neo4j doesn't support the use of indexes while looking into array with the `IN` clause.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. But here I want to refer to multiple endNodes(which will be a list of any size, and is not predefined), so how that can be tackled with Indexed search? logical predicates will not solve this problem. I am calling this method from Spring with a list of endNodes.